# golang code coverage in integration tests?

Tags: go, integration-testing

It seems the point of "go tool cover -var=foo" may be to generate instrumented code that can be deployed in an integration test harness.  Is anyone using this feature for that purpose?  If so, is there a conventional way to dump the counters periodically?  It seems the tricky part would be doing this across all files of interest with near simultaneity.  Even then, some skew (if using -mode=count) would be unavoidable.

Comment: Why do you want to dump the counters periodically? BTW: the `-var` flag is used to change the name of the counter which is useful only in special circumstances.

Comment: I want to profile my code running in a pre-production environment.  As I expect different paths to be taken at different times, I want to dump the counters periodically.  I think you will find that "go tool cover -mode=count -var=fooCtr foo.go > foo_i.go" provides you with an instrumented version of foo.go.  What "special circumstances" did you have in mind?

Comment: No, thats not how it works. `cover` is used to measure code coverage, it is completely unsuitable for profiling which is done by cmd `pprof` and package `runtime/pprof`. The "special circumstance" is when you want to instrument code which contains variables named  "GoCover" which is unlikely.

Comment: From go tool cover -help: "Finally, to generate modified source code with coverage annotations (what go test -cover does):
 go tool cover -mode=set -var=CoverageVariableName program.go"  I'm using the term "profile" informally.  The point of a unit test is to provide 100% coverage.  My app may only be using 10% of a given library.  I want to know which 10%.  Coverage is the right tool for what I need.

Comment: Instrumenting a third-party library to see which code path are used is a legitimate use case for the cover tool. But it is unlikely that you will have a *need* to use the `-var` flag, probably the default would be okay. Second: This use case does not answer my original question: Why do you want to dump the counters periodically? What would a conclusion like "The third-party library L used the following source code blocks B1 in second 12 of the execution of my program while it used a different set of blocks B2 during second 27."? What has this to do with 100% code coverage in unit testing?

Comment: Integration testing is all about getting the components wired up together and seeing common use cases fulfilled. It's not for verifying edge cases or tracking comprehensive code coverage.

Comment: I've noticed some Go projects are using [coveralls.io](https://coveralls.io/) to show the coverage of their tests. The projects below have the coveralls' coverage badge: * https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
* https://github.com/getlantern/lantern
* https://github.com/google/go-github It also allows to check coverage by file too. Check out this [lantern's commit][2] to see how it does it. It's free for open source projects. You can check out [their page](https://coveralls.io/) for pricing. I know this is a specific solution but I couldn't find anything better to get Go tests coverage... [

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We use this to collect code coverage from our various tests to get a single code coverage number across the tests and to see the uncovered code paths
* Module tests
* Integration tests
* UI tests
* API tests
* unit tests

The way to achieve this is

- Build an instrumented binary (app.debug) with coverage enables. The below command generates an app.debug with coverage instrumentation enabled

  ```
  $ go test -c -covermode=atomic -coverpkg="pkg/path/..." -o app.debug
  ```
- Use this app.debug instead of your app in the tests and run tests against it. Ours is an HTTP server but this should work for most applications. Each test generates a seperate cov file which later needs to be merged.

  ```
  $ ./app.debug -test.coverprofile=functest.cov -- app.params
  ```
- Merge all the test cov files to get a single cov file .For this, you can use [gocovmerge](https://github.com/wadey/gocovmerge)

  ```
  $ find $COVERAGE_DIR -name *.cov | xargs gocovmerge > final.cov
  ```

And you have finally a coverage file which gives you complete picture of code coverage from all sorts of coverage.